# How to fix ElasticSearch ‘Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default’ for keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm getting the "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default" on a keyword field. Below is the code.

```json
{
 "aggs": {
   "agg_terms_user": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "user"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The mapping for the **user** field is as below

```json
user: { type: "keyword" }
```

Since the user field has type set as keyword I shouldn't get the error. However, the error is still thrown.

> [illegal_argument_exception] Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [user] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.

I don't know what to try now.

Comment: use this in terms aggregation `"field": "user.keyword"`

Comment: That won't work. The user field is already set as keyword. Had I mapped it as user: {type: "text",fields: { keyword: { type: "keyword" } then it would have made sense to use "user.keyword"

Comment: oh, sorry..misunderstood. which ES version is this?

Comment: It's version 6.3

Comment: Make sure that `user` (or the field you are using) is of type `keyword` because this error is the one that ES rises when doing a term aggregation on a `text` field.

Comment: I've already mentioned in the question that it's keyword.

Comment: Share your mappings

Comment: I've added the mapping for the user above

Comment: Also, I've a doubt. How do I do range aggregation over a long field if it mandatory to keep it keyword

Comment: It's an intermittent issue. It works sometime while sometimes it fails. Also, it works just fine without error in one of the instance while it throws intermittent errors in the other. Both the instances are on AWS and have the exact same code. I checked the AWS ES configuration and I don't find anything suspicious. Am I missing anything

Comment: NO, your user field is text datatype, is written in the error stack Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [user] in order to load fielddata

Comment: maybe you have a subfield called user.keyword of type keyword

Comment: That's what I'm saying, This error is unexpected. It's keyword in my code and I don't have any subfield. Also, it works just fine in one instance of app while throws error in the other instance.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't subfield? Could you try {
 "aggs": {
   "agg_terms_user": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "user.keyword"
     }
   }
 }
}

Comment: How do you have taken your mapping? Could you please post the output of GET <your_index_name>/_mapping

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the reason behind the unexpected error. The ES wasn't getting re-indexed properly. Once I deleted the indexed first and then recreated it then it started working like a charm.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you did that? (v6.8)

Comment: Delete the index and recreate it.

Comment: Deleting indexes really helped and you can do in your server terminal using this command `curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/your_index_name'` and just in case you don't know the name of your index, you can use `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_search'` and you will see your index names. Replace your domain name and port if any changes in default setup.

Answer (score 38):

The [comment of @Andrey Borisko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298209/how-to-fix-elasticsearch-fielddata-is-disabled-on-text-fields-by-default-for-k#comment104800363_59298209) was correct

I used

```
"field": "user.keyword"
```

instead of

```
"field": "user"
```

based on Nikhil's example and it worked for me.

Comment: If you don't have access/permissions to change the index mappings and/or to re-index, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation in the elastic which clearly mentions that we cannot use the text field for **aggregations, sorting, or scripting**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param

This can be achieved with help of keyword usage. Try searching by

"field" : "user.keyword"

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue in heartbeat application.I have solved this issue by following below steps.

1. stop the application [ in my case I stopped the heartbeat
   application]
2. Delete the index related to apps.
3. Start the application